# SMS in modem's memory

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, web-server

I am working on SMS communication with my phone and Arduino. My intension is simple. When somebody send an SMS, the Arduino should read a text file located on my server and forward the content to the same number.

The problem here is, when I send an SMS to my Arduino, which is waiting for my message, it does not read my message. But when I separately run this [example code](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSMSMSRead), I see my SMS is received. It means my SMS is already present in the modem memory. But why does this happen? How to solve this? Here is my code:

```
// libraries
#include <GSM.h>

// PIN Number
#define PINNUMBER ""

// APN data
#define GPRS_APN       "GPRS_APN" // replace your GPRS APN
#define GPRS_LOGIN     "login"    // replace with your GPRS login
#define GPRS_PASSWORD  "password" // replace with your GPRS password

// initialize the library instance
GSMClient client;
GPRS gprs;
GSM gsmAccess; 
GSM_SMS sms;

// URL, path & port (for example: arduino.cc)
char server[] = "yourdomain.com";
char path[] = "/current.txt";
int port = 80; // port 80 is the default for HTTP

char k[30]; 
char z = '*';
int s=0;
String place;
char remoteNum[20];  // telephone number to send sms

void setup() {
    // initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
    }
    Serial.println("SMS connected");
    // connection state
    boolean notConnected = true;
    while(notConnected) {
        if((gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY) &
           (gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD)==GPRS_READY))
            notConnected = false;
        else {
            Serial.println("Not connected");
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
    Serial.println("GPRS connected...");
    Serial.println("Server Connecting.");
    // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    serverr();
}

void loop() {
    if (sms.available()) {
        Serial.println("Message received from:");
        sms.remoteNumber(remoteNum, 20);
        Serial.println(remoteNum);
        sms.flush();
        Serial.println("MESSAGE DELETED");
    }
}

void smss() {
  // I just want phone number
    if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        //***************************************************
        //       Filtering a specific message
        //**************************************************
        if (z==c) {
            s=1;
        }
        if(s == 1) {
            int i=0;
            k[i] = c;
            i=i+1;
            // Serial.print(k);
        }
        place +=k;
        //Serial.print(place);
    }
    //***************************************************  

    if (!client.available() && !client.connected()) {
        sms.beginSMS(remoteNum);
        Serial.print("Place =");
        Serial.print(place);
        sms.print(place);
        sms.endSMS(); 
        sms.flush();
        Serial.println("MESSAGE DELETED");
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("disconnecting.");
        client.stop();
        // do nothing forevermore:
        for(;;)
            ;
    }
}

// if you didn't get a connection to the server:
// Serial.print(server);

void serverr() {
    if (client.connect(server, port)) {
        client.print("GET /current.txt");
        Serial.print("GET /current.txt");
        client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
        Serial.println(" HTTP/1.1");
        client.println("Host: www.yourdomain.com");
        Serial.println("Host: www.yourdomain.com");
        client.println("User-Agent: Arduino");
        Serial.println("User-Agent: Arduino");
        client.println("Accept: text/html");
        Serial.println("Accept: text/html");
        client.println("Connection: close");
        Serial.println("Connection: close");
        client.println();
        Serial.println();

        Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");
        //client.stop();
    } else {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
        Serial.println("\n FAILED!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the content of `smss()` function, so that we can see how you read the SMS and then delete it.

Comment: I have given the function definition.

Comment: It would help if you told what debug messages get displayed on your serial monitor when running this program. Also, can you confirm that `remoteNumber` is defined as `char remoteNumber[20];`? Finally, I wonder if you can `flush()` an SMS without reading its content first.

Comment: In the serial monitor, It just waiting for my sms and stays static.But when i run this                 [code](arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSMSMSRead), I receive that sms.  Ya the its 'char remoteNumber[20];'.

Comment: the latest code you posted is obviously wrong: the `smss()` function  is **never** called. The global structure is just a mess as you did not break down behavior into different functions; instead some functions do a mix of unrelated actions.

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem with the global structure of your program; everytime `loop()` is run, it:

1. checks if an SMS is present, and gets the originating phone number if present, otherwise it just goes on, ie `smss()` function returns **without** modifying `remoteNumber`
2. send an SMS to `remoteNumber`

One problem here is that your `loop()` will repeatedly try to send an SMS to the same `remoteNumber` even if no SMS was received; actually, to solve this issue, you should modify `smss()` to:

- either **wait (forever) for an SMS to be received** and return only in this situation
- or **return a value (eg `bool`) that indicates whether an SMS was received** or not; then an SMS should be sent if and only if an SMS was just received.

Here is an example:

```
void setup()
{
    GSM and GPRS initialization
    Connection to server
} 

void loop()
{
    if (smss())
    {
        Reading the txt file content in server

        sms.beginSMS(remoteNum);
        sms.print(txtMsg);
        sms.endSMS(); 
    }
}

bool smss() // I just want phone number
{
    if (sms.available())
    {
        Serial.println("Message received from:");
        sms.remoteNumber(remoteNum, 20);
        Serial.println(remoteNum);
        sms.flush();
        Serial.println("MESSAGE DELETED");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that this code does not integrate error support as it should; indeed `sms.remoteNumber()` may return error codes (any value `>1`), in which case you should consider no SMS was received at all.

Comment: Will the sms.flush() will delete the content in remoteNum ? Because its in smss().

Comment: I have updated and added my void loop() in the question. But still,giving same problem

Comment: You've added much more to your code than just my suggestion; now we see how you get the text content from your server. And once again the whole logic of your program does not seem correct: write a function to fully read the **complete content** from your server (there **must be** a `while` inside it) instead of reading byte per byte at every call of `loop()`. And this problem is not linked to this specific question anymore.

Comment: I think, It would be better, If I give the complete code. I have updated the complete code. I have found a problem, If I don't run the `serverr()` function, I am able to receive sms, It means the `server()` conflicts the sms. Is my `serverr()` function correct ?